# How come I can cast/review close votes, but not have my edits apply immediately/review suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, editing, review

First off, I understand on a technical level that I can't do this because these are the milestones set by the site, but I wanted to know why it was this way.

On StackOverflow, you [require 3000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to cast a close/reopen votes and 2000 to review Suggested Edits. Here, it is reversed- you need [only 500 rep](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to cast close votes, and 1000 to get editing privileges (e.g. reviewing/instant edits).

My understanding of this reasoning is that it requires more *trust* to close questions than to make edits to them at StackOverflow. Why is it reversed for ELL? I couldn't find any discussion of this, and was curious about the reasoning. Was there some sort of problem before with lots of bad edits being made/approved? Why are the close/reopen privileges so easy to obtain here?

Comment: This is a Beta site, which went public less than a year ago. In these early days the requirements are all relaxed, so there are enough people people qualified to do the work. When we 'graduate' we'll have the same requirements as SO and other 'launched' sites.

Comment: @StoneyB I understand lowering the rep requirements, but why are they swapped like that? Why isn't it 500 for editing and 1000 to close instead of the reverse? Is it the same for **all** beta sites?

Comment: I imagine because figuring out what questions should be closed is more urgent in the site's first couple of weeks - that's when we're developing operational definitions of what is and is not on topic.

Comment: I had wondered if there was some reasoning like that, but was curious if there was some authoritative source for that decision. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, not *quite* authoritative, but @kiamlaluno is a mod at Drupal and a Founding Father here, too - [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123989)'s what he had to say about it on Meta.SO.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for and a great answer. I couldn't find anything like that before. That is definitely good enough for me.

Comment: This is either related to or a duplicate of http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/690/230